# Numbers $65x1y$ multiples of 12

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

Find all the five digit numbers in the form $65x1y$ multiples of $12$

Comment: OK, what's the problem?

Comment: Hint: We want (i) divisibility by $4$ and (ii) divisibility by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

The number to be found can be written as $N=65010+100x+y$, where $0\le x<10$ and $0\le y<10$ are the unknown digits. Therefore
$$
N=650\cdot 100+100x+10+y=4\cdot 25(650+x)+10+y
$$
which is divisible by $4$ if and only if $10+y$ is divisible by $4$, so if and only if $y=\dots$ (hint: there are two cases).

The number $N$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if
$$
6+5+x+1+y
$$
is divisible by $3$. Given the two choices for $y$, you'll find the possible values of $x$.

Comment: It would be better not to use $65x$ and $1y$ in the positional sense in arithmetic, as it can be confusing with the multiplies.  Instead you could say $65x1y$ can be written $65010+100x+y$ and do the same divisibility test.  I tripped on $1y$ thinking it was $1 \cdot y$.  Alternately you could underline to show the concatenation.  Your approach is a good one.

Comment: @RossMillikan I fixed the notation according to your advice.